# Select component MUI doesn't accept a Fragment as a child. Consider providing an array instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object, material-ui

I have several console errors because of this react function component, giving this error:

> Select component MUI doesn't accept a Fragment as a child. Consider
> providing an array instead

```
function CustomSelectGrouping({ reportList, label }) {
  return (
    <FormControl sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-select">{label}</InputLabel>
      <Select defaultValue="" id="grouped-select" label="Grouping">
        {Object.keys(reportList).map((head) => (
          <>
            <ListSubheader>{head}</ListSubheader>
            {reportList[head].map(({ id, name }) => <MenuItem value={id}>{`${id} - ${name}`}</MenuItem>)}
          </>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

I've already tried using React.Fragment and Render() but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Comment: "Consider providing an array instead". Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, but esLint is still finding errors using array

Comment: Whatever is inside that `Object.keys().map()` make it a separate component and it will stop complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Switch it to an array as was suggested by the library. It should look something like this

```
        Object.keys(reportList).map((head) => [
            <ListSubheader>{head}</ListSubheader>,
            ...reportList[head].map(({ id, name }) => <MenuItem value={id}>{`${id} - ${name}`}</MenuItem>),
        ])
```